# Swift Different Color for Each Action on UIAlertViewController.actionSheet

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uialertcontroller, xcode9

In swift, I am trying to add different colors to different buttons in a single option sheet. This is a sample:

```
let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

let reccommendAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Reccommend", style: .default, handler: {
    (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    print("Recommended")
})

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {
    (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    print("Cancelled")
})

optionMenu.addAction(reccommendAction)
optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

currentVC?.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The task I wish to complete is to make the `Recommend` button have a yellow tint color and the `Cancel` button to have a red tint color. I have tried using `optionMenu.view.tintColor`, however, that only allows for the setting of every cell, not individual ones.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change these colors. Be default when you are setting the action style to .cancel or .destructive it will have red color, it is enough in most cases. If you need to change this collors separately you have to create your own implementation of alert or use some already created libraries.